# phpStan extende method return type

Tags: php, phpstan

I have a class with two methods: `toArray` and `collect` where `collect` will return collection of array from method `toArray` responses. Is there any way in PHP Stan how to annotate return type for `collect` as array of `toArray` responses ? As shown in example bellow (except the fact that example bellow does not work) or do I have to copy-paste whole @return and extend it ?

```
class ExampleClass {
    /**
     * @return array{
     *     id: int,
     *     image: string,
     *     name: string,
     *     ...etc...
     * }
     */
    protected function toArray() {
        return [/*array filled with some data*/];
    }

    /**
     * Is there a valid way how to wrote this ?
     * @return array<int, self::toArray()>
     *
     */
    public function collect() {
        return [/* array of method toArray() responses */];
    }
}

Thanks !
```